# Cluster qsub check when job is done. python

Tags: python, cluster-computing, qsub

I'm building a python pipeline and in that pipeline script I call for another python script which uses qsub to submit a job to a cluster (this job consist op 70 jobs)
Now I need the output of those jobs to continue working.

How can I "Pause" the python script until all the 70 jobs are done?

I can't modify the script that submits to the server, so it has to be done in my own script.
(using an AMD64 cluster)

edit:

this is how I call the other script:

```
os.system("python ScriptThatQsub.py arg1 arg2")
```

I'm still working on this. and searching the interwebz, but I can't help but wonder... is this even possible??

Comment: Are you using Sun Grid Engine?  If so, then you can submit your own job with a -hold_jid <JOB_NAME> which will wait until the <JOB_NAME> jobs are complete before starting your job.

Comment: I think its Ganglia. Using Rocks clusters.
I'm still kind of new with clusters so I'm not so sure.

Comment: does qsub block?  See if it has a commandline option to wait until the job is finished.  On all servers that I've worked on, `qsub` returns right away and the server-side daemon takes over the job control from there.  If that's the case, I'm not sure how you can make it work apart from parsing the results of `showq` periodically (sleeping in between) and seeing if your job is still running/waiting.

Comment: Yes the qsub returns right away. that's where my problem comes in.

so.. I'd have to parse reults from showq to see if my job is still active? and sleep if that's the case?
(qstat in my case)

not ideal solution of course..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just put the Qstat from cluster in a variable and i checked if my jobname was found in that list. If so. sleep for a while. 
Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Just use the command line flag `-sync y` as in `qsub -sync y my_job` or

```
from subprocess import Popen
job = Popen(["qsub", "-sync", "y", "my_job"])
job.communicate()
```